# How can I correct editor.photoEditorDelegate = self?

Tags: ios, swift

I am still a beginner at Swift programming and I am trying to build a very basic iOS app. The app requires users to take a photo and edit them on a photo editor. I am having issues with using `editor.photoEditorDelegate = self`.

This is what the developer of the photo editor used in his example and it gave no problem but it's not working for me. It is giving an error of:

> Cannot assign value of type 'PhotosViewController?' to type 'PhotoEditorDelegate?'

I have tried to fix it with:

```
editor.photoEditorDelegate = self as? PhotoEditorDelegate
```

but it just makes the app crash when the editor is called.

I declared the editor with:

```
let editor = PhotoEditorViewController(nibName:"PhotoEditorViewController",bundle: Bundle(for: PhotoEditorViewController.self))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make your PhotosViewController your PhotoEditorDelegate:

```
class PhotosViewController: PhotoEditorDelegate {

...
```

Comment: This is a very low quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explanatory ! You need to add this delegate to your class name "PhotoEditorDelegate"

This is a sample code based on the information you have provided

```
class PhotosViewController: PhotoEditorDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let editor = PhotoEditorViewController(nibName:"PhotoEditorViewController",bundle: Bundle(for: PhotoEditorViewController.self))

       editor.photoEditorDelegate = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }



}
```

Comment: It's not "self-explanatory," and that's why the question was asked.

Comment: @Shades "Cannot assign value of type 'PhotosViewController?' to type 'PhotoEditorDelegate?'" How can this not be easy to understand ?